# How to update two entities on one endpoint?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I must create an function in my service to update my data in database, but i must to update data in two diffrent entities because i have a `@OneToOne` relations between  `UserEntity` and `DetailsEntity`, here is my entities:

UserEntity

```
@Entity()
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id!: number;

 //more an more...

  @OneToOne(
    () => Details,
    details=> details.user
  )
  details: Details;
}
```

DetailsEntity

```
@Entity()
export class Details{
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id!: number;

  @Column()
  userId: number;

  @OneToOne(() => User, {
    nullable: false,
    onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
  })
  @JoinColumn({
    name: 'userId',
  })
  user: User;

//more and more...

}
```

So, How can i update this two entities(with optional field) in only one service/controller?

what does my dto look like?

///////////////////////

Comment: Which resource is being updated? Are you calling to `/user` or to `/detail`? I know these are OnToOne, but _how_ are they related? What's special about User to Detail? Or is it actually Detail to User? There isn't enough to say what should look like what. Also, you had this same question up an hour ago. Keep the original question up. It doesn't do any good to otherwise delete a question and re-ask it.

Comment: @JayMcDoniel: I must using ```Detail``` entity which have a ```userId``` field

Comment: You must what? Update the Detail? Is there a need to update the User too? There's so much unknown that I can't begin to understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: Yes, i must update this two entities using only one service because i must send only one response to server which must include data to this two entites

Comment: Okay, but you haven't asnwered why **both** need the update? You're sending in a `Detail`, right? So why worry about `User`? It just doesn't make sense with what you've provided

Comment: because I need to update the information in both user and details on one enpoint : /

Comment: someone came up with and I have to write it this way

Comment: You may want to take a step back and think about what data needs to be updated for each entity. Right now, it's not clear what needs to be updated or how these two entities really relate to each other. "Because I need to update ... both" doesn't help determine what things should look like. Instead, think about what fields need to be updated, and how that should look as an incoming request. Think about what endpoint is being called. Think about how this all works together.

Answer (score 0):

Like other commenters have mentioned previously, I'm not entirely sure why it is being done it this way, but as someone who has worked on projects that have architectural issues that can't immediately be fixed, I'll try to help out.

You didn't include much detail with your problem so I'll just make some assumptions:

- You have an endpoint `/userDetails` that you are responding to a `PUT` or `POST` HTTP method.
- JSON body with properties where some will go to the `User` entity, and others going to `Detail` entity.

I would take the properties from the body and put them into objects for the user and detail entities.

Then create a typeorm transaction and insert/update both entities at the same time: [TypeORM Transactions](https://typeorm.io/#/transactions)

Some pseudo code:

```
const {body} = req;
const {
    username, addressLine1, city, state // etc...
} = body;
// User properties
const user = {
    username
};

// Detail properties
const detail = {addressLine1, city, state};

await getManager().transaction(async transactionalEntityManager => {
    await transactionalEntityManager.save(user);
    await transactionalEntityManager.save(detail);
    // ...
});
```